# Machine Learning. Ubuntu 16.04 vs 14.04?

Tags: compatibility

Which version is better for machine learning?

I have heard that 14.04 works better but I have ran into more that a few snags while using it (WiFi issues).  I want to shift to 16.04 but am afraid it might not work as well as 14.04 when it comes to machine learning.

I'll mostly be using Keras library and/or Caffe.

Comment: There is no better in regards to machine learning and this highly depends on the quality of your system. I would create a workflow so you can reinstall quickly if needed. Generally I would always go with the latest LTS (but that is not specific to machine learning).

Comment: I second @Rinzwind's comment....

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: If "Machine learning" is your goal, you can minimize the major system upgrades and ensure support availability  by sticking to the Long Term Support (`LTS`) releases of Ubuntu. 16.04LTS is the most recent LTS release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whichever release that **works best for the hardware**.

The release that works well with your hardware would be the most relevant choice, given that machine learning tools are capable of running on [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)-enabled graphic processing unit (GPU). Both [Keras](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-keras-on-gpu) and [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#hardware) seems to have been tested running on some hardware models.

When your hardware support is good, then only look at how to install the packages. Apparently, which release to use *does not really matter* according to the documentation for Keras and Caffe.

From [documentation for Keras](https://keras.io/#installation):

> Keras is compatible with: Python 2.7-3.5.
>
> You can install Keras from PyPI (easiest method):
>
> ```
> sudo pip install keras
> ```

From [documentation for Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html):

> Caffe has several dependencies:
>
> - CUDA is required for GPU mode.
>
>   - library version 7+ and the latest driver version are recommended, but 6.* is fine too
>   - 5.5, and 5.0 are compatible but considered legacy
> - BLAS via ATLAS, MKL, or OpenBLAS.
>
>   - Boost `>= 1.55`
>   - `protobuf`, `glog`, `gflags`, `hdf5`

[The instruction](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html) to install Caffe varies by Ubuntu releases.

For Ubuntu (>= 17.04)

> CPU-only version:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install caffe-cpu
> ```
>
> CUDA-version:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install caffe-cuda
> ```

Installation seems to be easy on newer releases of Ubuntu. On the other hand, packages must be installed separately on releases older than 17.04 (ouch).

Note that I have merely quoted relevant information from the documentation for Keras and Caffe; I have no experience for using these tools.

One thing for sure: Most users wouldn't want to deal with trivial issues i.e. unable to use Wi-Fi connection, screen tearing, etc. even before attempting to install the desired packages. Hence my suggestion to use whichever release that works best for the hardware. That comes first.